# How do I find the starting memory address of another application with C#

Tags: c#, memory, process

The offset of a game in cheat engine is 0x02406B68. The sum of the game's .exe and offset is 0BEA4CC0. As shown below.
anygame.exe + 02406B68 = 0BEA4CC0
[pointer offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCvSE.jpg
My problem is that I can't find the memory address of the game's .exe correctly with C# and the values ​​are different from the cheat engine.Many thanks to anyone who can help with this.
This is my code

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Metin2Client")\[0\];
IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);

       int bytesRead = 0;
       byte[] buffer = new byte[16]; 

       ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text,16), buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);

       richTextBox1.Text = bytesRead.ToString();
       richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0);
```